# Wait with transition for element to be dropped @dnd-kit React

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, dnd-kit

I'm using @dnd-kit in my React project and I try to insert elements from lower list to the upper list. I want to control the transition of placeholder to wait until the element gets inserted, so it does not jump. Unfortunately the transition happens because class `expanded` is gone when `isOver` is false. Does anyone have an idea how I can first wait for the insertion and then do the transition? Here is a link to the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/friendly-moser-ih8v08

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got what you need but this is what I did:

In CartItem.tsx add:

you can use transition but you need to switch to useSortable, which works quite the same.

```
import {useSortable} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import { CSS } from "@dnd-kit/utilities";

const {
    isDragging,
    setNodeRef,
    attributes,
    listeners,
    transform,
    transition,
  } = useSortable({
    id: item,
    data: {
      text: item,
      position,
      type,
    },
  });

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
    transition,
    opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
  };
```

In App.tsx I changed DraggEnd and DraggStart. First it width is set to 0 and then after dragg end it is set to width.

```
  function handleDragStart(event: DragStartEvent) {
    const { active } = event;
    setPlaceholderWidth(0);
    setActiveId(active.id.toString());
    setActivePosition(active.data.current?.position);
  }

  function handleDragEnd(event: DragEndEvent) {
    setActiveId(null);
    setActivePosition(-1);
    const { active, over } = event;
    const activeElement = document.getElementById(active.id.toString());
    if (activeElement) {
      const rect = activeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const { width } = rect;
      setPlaceholderWidth(width);
    }
```

It is not the best solution but I hope it helped.

PS. If you have a problem with animation of dropping you can change it using [drop-animation](https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable/drag-overlay#drop-animation) prop

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, there is no `transition` value that can be extracted from `useDraggable` hook: https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable/usedraggable#properties. Moreover, I need the placeholder to be displayed on drag over, setting placeholder width to 0 on drag start makes it hidden.

Comment: you are right about transition, I made an update